# What is the optimal StringBuffer initial capacity for inputs with drastically varying lengths?

Tags: java, math, language-agnostic, buffer, stringbuilder

Good afternoon all, I'm using a [java.lang.StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to store some characters. I have no idea how many characters I'm going to store in advance, except that:

1. 60% of the time, it is only (exactly) 7 characters
2. 39% of the time, it is (roughly) 3500 characters
3. 1% of the time, it is roughly 20k characters

How do we go about calculating the optimal initial buffer length that should be used?

<sub>Currently I'm using `new java.lang.StringBuilder(4000)` but that's just because I was too lazy to think previously.</sub>

Comment: It sounds like default could be optimal most of the time. Can you re-cycle your StringBuilders?

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: @PeterLawrey No they aren't recyclable (I mean they *could* be, and I believe that would be much more optimal however it would require a change to source code).

Comment: @natix Fear of premature optimization is part of the reason I inserted 4000 and be-done-with-it in the first place. However now that it is *post-mature*, it isn't too hard to simply change the argument of a constructor is it?

Comment: Any change would require a change to source code.  You can make the objects reuseable without an object pool style recycling.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Lol you got me =) I actually meant "it would require a change to the logic of the already-written class if I make it reuseable". I was actually thinking of just getting a bit of optimization by tweaking a single number.

Comment: I would stick with the initial capacity. If the performance problems become observable, only then I would use a profiler and **measure** the performance with various capacity settings. Blind guessing doesn't help here, moreover you're probably needlessly allocating quite amounts of memory.

Comment: Similar Question, [Most efficient initial capacity size for StringBuilder?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13360229/642706).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two factors here: time and memory consumption. The time is mostly influenced by the number of times `java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity()` is called. Of course the cost of each call is linear to the current size of the buffer, but I am simplifying here and just counting them:

## Number of `expandCapacity()` (time)

### Default configuration (16 characters capacity)

- In 60% of the cases the `StringBuilder` will expand 0 times
- In 39% of the cases the `StringBuilder` will expand 8 times
- In 1% of the cases the `StringBuilder` will expand 11 times

The expected number of `expandCapacity` is 3,23.

### Initial capacity of 4096 characters

- In 99% of the cases the `StringBuilder` will expand 0 times
- In 1% of the cases the `StringBuilder` will expand 3 times

The expected number of `expandCapacity` is 0,03.

As you can see the second scenario seems much faster, as it very rarely has to expand the `StringBuilder` (three time per every 100 inputs). Note however that first expands are less significant (copying small amount of memory); also if you add strings to the builder in huge chunks, it will expand more eagerly in less iterations.

On the other hand the memory consumption grows:

## Memory consumption

### Default configuration (16 characters capacity)

- In 60% of the cases the `StringBuilder` will occupy 16 characters
- In 39% of the cases the `StringBuilder` will occupy 4K characters
- In 1% of the cases the `StringBuilder` will occupy 32K characters

The expected average memory consumption is: **1935** characters.

### Initial capacity of 4096 characters

- In 99% of the cases the `StringBuilder` will occupy 4K characters
- In 1% of the cases the `StringBuilder` will occupy 32K characters

The expected average memory consumption is: **4383** characters.

---

## TL;DR

This makes me believe that enlarging the initial buffer to 4K will increase the memory consumption by more than two times while speeding up the program by two *orders of magnitude*.

The bottom line is: try! It is not that hard to write a benchmark that will process million strings of various length with different initial capacity. But I believe a bigger buffer might be a good choice.