# Is using constants like INTEGR_ONE a good way, why can't we use the 1 itself?

Tags: java, constants, coding-style

In my project I have seen many places where constants like INTEGER_ONE, INTEGER_ZERO are used. What is the purpose of using like this? We use constants to change the value in one place that automatically reflects everywhere for particular case, but using constants like INTEGER_ONE is same like using 1, it is common value irrespective of the case they will be using in all places. When we need to change the value of one from the place we obviously need to visit there and change that to another value like INTEGER_N. So why can't we use the numbers directly?

Comment: You are on the right track. Don’t use constants like `INTEGER_ONE`. Compare with [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41829237/2711488).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go through the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#INTEGER_ONE), you will find that, `INTEGER_ONE` is stated as:

> Reusable Integer constant for one.

And, the actual declaration of `INTEGER_ONE` is:

```
public static final Integer INTEGER_ONE = Integer.valueOf(1);
```

In Java, values between `-128` and `127` are kept in `IntegerCache` for reuse. So, if you call `Integer.valueOf()` method with parameter from the specified range, in that case, the same object will be returned all the time. As object creation is expensive, this is one kind of optimization, if you have to use Integer.

But, if you are using primitive types, like `int`, then there is no need to use `INTEGER_ONE`, you can directly use `1`.

Comment: Help me in this also.
What is the difference between date.plusdays(INTEGER_ONE) vs date.plusdays(1)?
which is best to use and why?

Comment: @Prasath just use `plusdays(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a style rule of not using magic constants. Like `7` - days of week, `DAYS_IN_WEEK`? However `INTEGER_ONE` is for any kind of usage for `1` is IMHO even worse.

There is a use case: constant object, to share. `BigDecimal.ZERO` is such a case.
Should `INTEGER_ONE` not be an `int` but the wrapper object `Integer` then you can share the same object, and need not create a plethora of Integer objects with the same value.
However `Integer.valueOf(n)` would also give the same object for values between -128 and 127. In general one should not work with the wrapper classes; Integer here, when using the int values. However collections like `List<Integer>` use Integers.